# Trying to find a data which is not visible in the source code

Tags: web, web-scraping

Hey as the title suggest, I have been trying to get a specific data which is being assigned but not shown by the website.
I frankly am completely new to coding and data scraping.
But I need to see this data for work which is gonna help me.

https://v2.gcchmc.org/book-appointment/ this is the website and after you select your country, city and country travelling too it shows your medical center is assigned which is the value im trying to find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or links to learn how to find this data.

Comment: It's probably loading it at runtime via JavaScript, and so won't show up in the HTML.

Comment: Yes, agree with Andy Lester. Check out this q/a about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678670/cannot-scrape-amazon-data-beautifulsoup-returns-empty-html-element